# How can I define this value(s) in a good and easy way?

Tags: c++

I am stuck in a conversion / definition of a function parameter and would very much appreciate some help. I am sure it's an easy one for any experienced c/c++ guy, but not for me, not right now.

**Problem:**

creating the right parameter to use with `myCommmand(uint8 *pAddr)`, which will execute `send(pAddr, 6)`, which will use those parameters to loop the following 6 times:

`write(reinterpret_cast<unsigned char*>(pAddr)[i]);`

my trouble is, that pAddr has to point to an array of 6 bytes, which i most preferably would like to define as unsigned byte values (0-255) or as hex 00-FF.

**Restrictions**

Functions shall not be changed. It is just about creating the parameters.

**My attempts:**

```
uint8 Addr[] = {00,22,122,205,16,04};
uint8 *pAddr = &Addr;
```

but this results in error C2440 (can't convert uint(*)[6] to uint8 *).

**Desired solution**

I would like to know a *good*, wellformed way to create this Addr-array or stream, or object to pass on to my functions, by writing their byte or hex values into my code - like in my attempt. I can use *boost*-libraries. Thanks to all helping me out with this!

Comment: Have you tried `uint8 *pAddr = Addr;` ?

Comment: Just use `Addr`, an array will decay into a pointer to its first element when needed. The explicit way to do this would be `&Addr[0]`. :)

Comment: seriously - _doh_ - maybe it's just to early or i am still not getting those pointer definitions - your hint works ;) but would you mind extending this to an input of hex values? so I could write 16 intead of 22?

Comment: Maybe you need [a book](http://tinyurl.com/so-cxxbooks)? For writing hex, use `0xNN`, like `0xFF` for 255.

Comment: Yes you are right, I have some, but I need some time to study this stuff again - will keep this in mind before asking more basic stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried

```
uint8 Addr[] = {0x0,0x16,0x7a,0xcd,0x10,0x4};
uint8 *pAddr = Addr;
```

?

*Note:* Do not use `0` prefix! It means the number is in octal, so `010` means `8` in dec.